# My script keeps putting "your logged in" in boxes in top left

Tags: php

```
<?php include('_header.php'); ?>

<?php
// if you need the user's information, just put them into the $_SESSION variable and output them here
echo WORDING_YOU_ARE_LOGGED_IN_AS . $_SESSION['user_name'] . "<br />";
//echo WORDING_PROFILE_PICTURE . '<br/><img src="' . $login->user_gravatar_image_url . '" />;
echo WORDING_PROFILE_PICTURE . '<br/>' . $login->user_gravatar_image_tag;
?>

<div>
<a href="index.php?logout"><?php echo WORDING_LOGOUT; ?></a>
<a href="edit.php"><?php echo WORDING_EDIT_USER_DATA; ?></a>
</div>

<?php include('_footer.php'); ?>
```

After logging in when it displays the "you are logged in" it is in the top left corner of my page and I need it in the top right corner.

I have tried multiple methods and none of them seem to solve my issue

here is the _header.php file, I have tried finding the "your logged in" section but unable to locate it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>php-login-advanced</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* just for the demo */
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            margin: 10px;
        }
        label {
            position: relative;
            vertical-align: middle;
            bottom: 1px;
        }
        input[type=text]
        {    position: absolute;  
             display: block;
             top: 45px;
             right: 30px;
            }            

    input[type=password]
    {    position: absolute;
         display: block;
         top: 80px;
         right: 30px;
        }            
    input[type=submit]
    {    position: absolute;
         display: block;
         top: 115px;
         right: 30px;
        }            
    input[type=email] {      
        top: 30px;
        right: 25px;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    input[type=checkbox] {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// show potential errors / feedback (from login object)
if (isset($login)) {
if ($login->errors) {
    foreach ($login->errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
    }
}
if ($login->messages) {
    foreach ($login->messages as $message) {
        echo $message;
        }
    }
}
?>

<?php
// show potential errors / feedback (from registration object)
if (isset($registration)) {
    if ($registration->errors) {
        foreach ($registration->errors as $error) {
            echo $error;
        }
    }
    if ($registration->messages) {
        foreach ($registration->messages as $message) {
            echo $message;
        } 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: isn't this a css/html alignment problem?

Comment: Do you have any CSS / styles yet? If not.. you need to start there. (Also, you'll want "You're logged in")

Comment: Can you tell us what's inside `header.php`, please? It looks like you're just echoing your "logged in" message directly onto the page, but you really should be doing it inside a `<div>` or other block element if you want to position it somewhere other than it's normal "raw" position in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Add `style="float:right;"` to the div

Or better put this in a separate CSS file, in a CSS class declaration, and add the class to you div.

It would be something like

```
<div class="pull-right">
```

Add in the head of your HTML file :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css" />
```

And in the mycss.css file:

```
.pull-right {
    float:right;
}
```